# How to force Gmail/Android to request password every time for google account

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, security, gmail, password, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logout from Gmail on my device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18972/logout-from-gmail-on-my-device)

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace running Android 2.3.3. Is it possible to force Gmail or any google related apps to request my password everytime I open them?

I don't like how Android syncs with my account and the only way I can protect my phone is by setting up a screen pattern lock or pin, if I wanted to show my phone to people I can't without them able to fiddle around through my emails once its unlocked or if I leave it lying around before it locks.

IOS has something like that on iTunes or App Store where you always have to put in your password.

Comment: If you don't like how Android syncs with your Google account (a major selling point) why in the world did you get an Android?

Comment: @Al: lots of people make exactly the same decision because choice is extremely limited and it appears as the lesser of two evils. That doesn't mean people love the loss of privacy or control built into every Android device. If you need a smartphone, Android is obviously, hands-down the lesser evil. If your question is "why would you buy a smartphone at all?", than you're stepping onto a slippery slope: you could just as easily say "why would you like to use a phone?" because someone  e.g. doesn't like his phone company knowing who he talks to and what about...

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you can do anything natively except disconnect the account you're syncing with every time you're done checking your mail.

However, there are [a number of app protect apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=app%20lock&so=1&c=apps) out there that let you put passwords on particular apps for just such a purpose.