# How can i logout from my gmail account

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google-talk

how can i logout from my gmail account from my mobile phone? my mobile phone is sony erricson XPERIA U.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Erica! Could you please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46464/edit) your question to include some more details: What do you want to achieve by logging out of GMail? This would help us to find the best solution for you.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Logout from Gmail on my device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18972), although it's hard to tell if you're talking about a web browser, the Gmail app, etc (seems like you likely are, though).

Answer (score 2):

You can't without deleting your Google Account from your phone as far as I'm aware. You can do this in your phone settings. Why would you want to though?

If you are concerned about people seeing or using your email, set a PIN or pattern lock on your phone.

Alternatively, remove your Google Account completely and use Google's web based versions of Gmail, etc. All of those you can log into and out of at will - obviously a lot less convenient though.