# Log off on Nexus 7 2013 V4.3

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

Can you log off gmail on Nexus 7 2013 V4.3 ?  I would like to share tablet (to play games) without them reading my mail. I do not wish to open up new accounts. Thanx

Comment: [Logout from Gmail on my device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18972)

Answer (score 1):

`Settings -> Sync -> Google` : untick Gmail.

`Settings -> Applications -> Gmail` : Clear Data, Uninstall updates, Disable.